# django paginate with non-model object

Tags: django, django-models, pagination, django-views

I'm working on a side project using python and Django. It's a website that tracks the price of some product from some website, then show all the historical price of products.

So, I have this class in Django:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  price = models.FloatField()
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
  name = models.CharField()
```

Then, in my views.py, because I want to display products in a table, like so:

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+....
| Name     | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 |...     |....
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+....
| Product1 | 100.0  | 120.0  | 70.0   | ...    |....
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+....
...
```

I'm using the following class for rendering:

```
class ProductView(objects):
  name = ""
  price_history = {}
```

So that in my template, I can easily convert each product_view object into one table row. I'm also passing through context a sorted list of all available dates, for the purpose of constructing the head of the table, and getting the price of each product on that date.

Then I have logic in views that converts one or more products into this ProductView object. The logic looks something like this:

```
def conversion():
  result_dict = {}
  all_products = Product.objects.all()
  for product in all_products:
    if product.name in result_dict:
      result_dict[product.name].append(product)
    else:
      result_dict[product.name] = [product]
  # So result_dict will be like 
  # {"Product1":[product, product], "Product2":[product],...}
  product_views = []
  for products in result_dict.values():
    # Logic that converts list of Product into ProductView, which is simple.
  # Then I'm returning the product_views, sorted based on the price on the 
  # latest date, None if not available.
  return sorted(product_views, 
                key = lambda x: get_latest_price(latest_date, x),
                reverse = True)
```

As per Daniel Roseman and zymud, adding get_latest_price:

```
def get_latest_price(date, product_view):
  if date in product_view.price_history:
    return product_view.price_history[date]
  else:
    return None
```

I omitted the logic to get the latest date in conversion. I have a separate table that only records each date I run my price-collecting script that adds new data to the table. So the logic of getting latest date is essentially get the date in OpenDate table with highest ID.

So, the question is, when product grows to a huge amount, how do I paginate that product_views list? e.g. if I want to see 10 products in my web application, how to tell Django to only get those rows out of DB?

I can't (or don't know how to) use django.core.paginator.Paginator, because to create that 10 rows I want, Django needs to select all rows related to that 10 product names. But to figure out which 10 names to select, it first need to get all objects, then figure out which ones have the highest price on the latest date.

It seems to me the only solution would be to add something between Django and DB, like a cache, to store that ProductView objects. but other than that, is there a way to directly paginate produvt_views list?

Comment: Can you sort products in query and don`t sort them as product_views?

Comment: You need to move the sorting logic to the database. What is `get_latest_price`? Maybe it can be done via annotations, or perhaps raw SQL.

Comment: hey Daniel and zymud, I've edited the post to include the logic of get_latest_price. As you see, I'm trying to sort the list by the price on the latest date given to the function. Therefore I don't think I can sort it in DB, as for those products that are not available on "the latest date", they will be at the bottom, therefore they won't be included when getting the list to construct ProductView object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if this makes sense:

The basic idea is, since I'll need to sort all product_views by the price on the "latest" date, I'll do that bit in DB first, and only get the list of product names to make it "paginatable". Then, I'll do a second DB query, to get all the products that have those product names, then construct that many product_views. Does it make sense?

To clear it a little bit, here comes the code:

So instead of

```
#def conversion():
  all_products = Product.objects.all()
```

I'm doing this:

```
#def conversion():
  # This would get me the latest available date
  latest_date = OpenDate.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]
  top_ten_priced_product_names = Product.objects
      .filter(date__in = latest_date)
      .order_by('-price')
      .values_list('name', flat = True)[:10]
  all_products_that_i_need = Product.objects
      .filter(name__in = top_ten_priced_product_names)
  # then I can construct that list of product_views using
  # all_products_that_i_need
```

Then for pages after the first, I can modify that [:10] to say [10:10] or [20:10].

This makes the code pagination easier, and by pulling appropriate code into a separate function, it's also possible to do Ajax and all those fancy stuff.

But, here comes a problem: this solution needs three DB calls for every single query. Right now I'm running everything on the same box, but still I want to reduce this overhead to two(One or Opendate, the other for Product).

Is there a better solution that solves both the pagination problem and with two DB calls?